# QGIS Calculate Attribute Value from sum of dependent Point features

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, attribute-table, trace

I have two layers one with line geometry and other with point geometry. Features from both the layers are perfectly snapped.

In the line layer, I want to calculate the field which is depend on features in point layer. It is like calculating value on the basis of downstream trace from line end point to the further till last end point.

The line attribute value is depends on the accumulating sum value of point feature attribute towards downstream. (From line end point to actual last line end point. Flow direction added.)[image]

Like in the image, the selected line should get the value from downwards point (as per the flow direction) attribute as a sum of their values `(10+9+0+7+8)`. I am not getting any idea about how can i make it.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you clarify this question.  It would help if you added direction of travel arrows, nodes where lines split, and clarified which points are counted.  Specifically, you have circled a 10 and 8 and there are two points with an attribute of 8.  My guess is you want to count the 8 which isn't circled, at the end of the line.

Comment: @jgm_GIS, I updated the image with flow direction. I want to update the selected line attribute (circled line) as per the sum of point present in the downstream of that line (10+9+0+7+8).